# How can I get the list of NuGet packages available for KRuntime?

Tags: asp.net-core, kruntime

It looks like [only a part of BCL is supported for KRuntime](http://forums.asp.net/post/5717978.aspx). Is there a list of the assemblies in BCL that will be supported? [ASP.NET vNext repositories](https://github.com/aspnet) don't include any of the System.* libraries. It would be useful to check if a library can be ported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found useful this myget gallery for asp.net vnext [dev branch](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext) or [master branch](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetmaster)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET vNext has a package feed on MyGet. It looks like we can query it with [NuGet.exe](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939).

```
NuGet.exe list -Source "https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2"
```

**Update:**

Checking the feed with [NuGet Package Explorer](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864) is a better alternative. You can easily open up package contents and see if KRuntime is supported. As far as I can see, not all of the packages listed there are supported on KRuntime.